# How to navigate between two viewcontrollers using a UIPickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I am trying to navigate between two viewcontrollers using a UIPickerview, so i first learned how to use didSelectRow to change the title of a label and then i tried using some code to navigate to another viewcontroller but that didn't work.

The code that i used was:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
var food = ["hello", "hi", "hey"]

var placementAnswer = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return food.count 
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return food[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    placementAnswer = row
}

@IBAction func labelChanged(sender: UIButton) {

    if (placementAnswer == 0){

    }else if (placementAnswer == 1){

        let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! ViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

    }else if (placementAnswer == 2){
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is your self.navigationController a valid object or is it nil. Is a navigationController actually being used.

Comment: yes this is the rest of the code:     @IBAction func labelChanged(sender: UIButton) {
    
        if (placementAnswer == 0){
            
        
        
        }else if (placementAnswer == 1){
            
            
            let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! ViewController2
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
            
            
        }else if (placementAnswer == 2){
    
    
    }

}

}

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in labelChanged and check if it actually getting invoked?

Answer (score 0):

As paranoidcoder pointed out I'm not sure your labelChanged method is getting called, which could be the problem with your existing code.

I'm assuming you want to change the view controller after a certain row is selected in the picker view. Putting the if statement to change views in didSelectRow would make the most sense in that case.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) 
 {
     placementAnswer = row // unnecessary variable

     if (placementAnswer == 0){}
     else if (placementAnswer == 1)
     {
        let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as! ViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
     }
     else if (placementAnswer == 2) {}
}
```